# Angularjs directive with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I am new to Angularjs and are trying to create a dictionary directive that searches and replaces texts with anchor tags. The search and replace part works fine but i can't get the ng-click to work. 
**HTML**

```
<div mk-dct>Lorem ipsum [dolor] sit [amet]</div>
```

**Angular**

```
app.directive('mkDct', function () {
var pattern = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var txt = element.html();
        var m = txt.match(pattern);

        for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
            var word = m[i].substring(1, m[i].length-1);
            txt = txt.replace(m[i], '<a class="dict-item" ng-click="func(\''+word+'\')" href="#">'+ word + '</a>');
        }

        element.html(txt);
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**
The commented lines below made it work as expected.

```
app.directive('mkDct', function ($compile) {
var pattern = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var txt = element.html();
        var m = txt.match(pattern);

        for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
            var word = m[i].substring(1, m[i].length-1);
            txt = txt.replace(m[i], '<a class="dict-item" ng-click="func(\''+word+'\')" href="#">'+ word + '</a>');
        }

        // Compile to template.
        txt = $compile(txt)(scope);

        // Clear and append.
        element.empty().append(txt);
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#!) your element.

**EDIT**
Add compile statement after loop as discussed in comments below.

```
txt = $compile(txt)(scope);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this creates an error  "txt.replace is not a function". Btw: I included $compile in the directives main function declaration to get $compile to work.

Comment: @Andbil, use `compile` after loop

Comment: I included the compile after the loop like this: txt = $compile(txt); This seems to output the code of the link function starting i with "function publicLinkFn..."

Comment: @Andbil, yep, you need link compiled element with scope, so it should be like `$compile(txt)(scope)`

Comment: Great! In conjunction with append() and empty() instead of just html() it worked. Thanks guys and will update the code with the solution.